# Looking for a simple outliner

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, editor

Back in the day i used [OmniOutliner](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnioutliner/) a lot. Is there something like that for GNOME? Google suggested me [Gnome Outliner](http://gnomeoutliner.sourceforge.net/) and a friend of mine mentioned [TreeSheets](http://www.treesheets.com/).

But is there something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you feel comfortable with vim, I suggest [VimOutliner](https://github.com/vimoutliner/vimoutliner).

Answer (score 0):

For GNU Emacs there is also an [Outline Mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/OutlineMode). You can activate it with <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>outline-mode</kbd>. A good example is the [Emacs NEWS file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.23.1) (open it with <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>C-n</kbd>). Different header levels are marked with `*`.

```
* Level 1
** Level 2
text between
*** Level 3
more text
```

You can show all by pressing <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd> and show only headings with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-t</kbd>. The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Mode.html#Outline-Mode) has a more detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old post but for the benefit of others who may be looking for an outliner as well, for what it's worth, I've just released a Gtk 2.0 based outliner for Ubuntu and derivatives (such as Mint) called *Hiero*. It's certainly no OmniOutliner but that said, it's targeted for use by those wanting to draft blog articles, dissertations, etc. (although it can also be used to manage "to do" lists as well). You can read more about it on my blog, Productive Penguin (http://productivepenguin.blogspot.com/2015/07/an-outliner-for-linux.html).